# How to bind a property with the UserControl type to SplitView.Control using the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, xml, mvvm, avalonia

I want to bind a property with the UserControl type to SplitView.Content so that changing the property when the button is clicked would change the content. For some reason, data binding does not work for me, although I wrote everything as in the documentation.

Here is the code from the MainView.axaml file in the View folder:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="AutoSwithcer.Avalonia.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="using:AutoSwithcer.Avalonia.ViewModels"
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="800"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Styles>
        <Style Selector="Button">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="7" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Styles>

    <SplitView Name="SplitView"
               Content="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}"
           DisplayMode="Inline"
               IsPaneOpen="True"
               OpenPaneLength="200">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <DockPanel Margin="7">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">Settings</Button>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <StackPanel Spacing="7">
                        <Button>Home</Button>
                        <Button>Switching rules</Button>
                        <Button>App rules</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DockPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
    </SplitView>

</UserControl>
```

and here is the code from the MainViewViewModel.cs file in the ViewModel folder:

```cs
public class MainViewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private UserControl _content;
    public UserControl Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _content, value); }
    }

    public MainViewViewModel()
    {
        _content = new HomeView();
    }
}
```

Switching between pages when clicking on the button from the sidebar

Comment: The binding shouldn't need to be TwoWay because the SplitView doesn't try to set it's own Content at any time.  I don't think it's a problem, which is why I'm not putting this as an answer, but I don't see anything else wrong.  If this started from a default template, check App.axaml.cs and make sure the MainView DataContext is being assigned (it should be, but I've seen stranger things)

Comment: Just a quick question, why dont you just use an UI composer, like Prism?

Comment: @mmix Why would you add an extra dependency just to do something that the UI language can do?

Comment: @Tarazed because he is obviously creating a navigable app and Prism et al already have all the nuts and bolts in place. We've been trading complexity for convenience since the time of asm.

Comment: @mmix All he wants to do is get his binding working.  How is installing and learning another package than the one he is using trading complexity for convenience?

Comment: @Tarazed because I am pretty sure this is not the extent of his UI navigation requirement and his question is more complex than the simple binding issue. Besides, he should learn at least one UI compositor framework for personal growth.